# Unable to connect Raspberry to Wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, connection, raspberry-pi-os

I want to connect my Raspberry to Internet through Wifi, but it can't detect any Wifi. I've read that only Pi 3 and + models can do that, but mine is a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev (see picture). Any thoughts?

[image: Seems no wifi is detected despite this model should be able to]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What returns this command `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` ?

If you see your wifi listed then do following:

1. Put your ssid and pw below existing content by editing this file `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
   ssid="WIFI SSID"
   psk="WIFI PW"
}
```

2. Reboot

If your Pi still can't connect to the wifi, check if the WiFi adapter is enabled with this command

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

And don't forget to remove LAN cable

Comment: Why is removing the LAN cable so important ?

Comment: it might prefer to connect to the internet via LAN @MatsK

Comment: Please read the question again ! And then I think you will erase the LAN part.